# Create idex with repeated data

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have data from an external source that is downloaded in csv format. This data shows the interactions from several users and doesn't have an id column. The problem I'm having is that I'm not able to use index because multiple entries represent interactions and processes. The interactions would be the group of processes a specific user do and the  process represents each actions taken in a specific interaction. Any user could repeat the same interaction at any time of day. The data looks likes this:

[image]

User1 has 2 processes but there were 3 interactions. How can I assign an ID for each interaction having into consideration that there might be multiple processes for a single user in the same day. I tried grouping them in Power Query but it groups the overall processes and I'm not able to distinguish the number of interactions. Is it better to do it in Dax?

**Edit:**

I notice that it is hard to understand what I need but I think this would be a better way to see it:

[image]

Process 2 are the steps done in an interaction. Like in the column in yellow I need to add an ID taking in to consideration where an interaction start and where it ends.

Comment: What constitutes an "interaction"?  Which of the rows represent the three interactions of User 1?  What would you expect for output?

Comment: I updated the original post in order to show the final output I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure I follow what you describe. It looks to me like user1 has 4 interactions--Processes AA, AB, BA, and BB--but you say 3.

Still, I decided to take a shot at providing an answer anyway. I started with a CSV file set up like you show.

[image]

Then brought the CSV into Power Query and, just to add a future point of reference so that you could follow the Id assignments better, I added an index column that I called startingIndex.

[image]

Then I added a custom column combining the processes that I understand actually define an interaction.

[image]

Then I grouped everything by users and Interactions into a column named allData.

[image]

[image]

Then I added a custom column to copy the column that was created from the earlier grouping, to sort the tables within it, and to add an index to each table within it. This essentially indexed each user's interaction group. *(Because all of your interactions occur on the same date(s), the sorting doesn't help much. But I did it to show where you could do it if you included datetime info instead of just a date.)*

[image]

[image]

Then I added a custom column to copy the column that was created earlier to add the interactions index, and to add an Id item within each table within it. I constructed each Id by combining the user, interactions, and interactionIndex for each.

[image]

[image]

Then I selected the latest column I had created (complexId) and removed all other columns.

[image]

Last, I expanded all tables without including the Interactions and Index columns. (The Index column was the index used for the interactions within the groups and no longer needed.) I included the startingIndex column just so you could see where items originally were at the start, in comparison to their final Id.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried something similar but didn't worked as expected. I updated the original question so it could a little bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Given your new example, to create the Interaction ID you show, you only need the first two columns of the table. *If not part of the original data, you can easily generate the third column (Process2))*

It appears you want to increment the interaction ID whenever the Process changes

Please read the comments in the M code and explore the Applied Steps to better understand the algorithm:

**M Code**

```
let

//be sure to change table name in next row to your real table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"User", type text},
        {"Process", type text},
        {"Process2", type text}
    }), 

//add an index column
    idx = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Custom column returns the Index if
//   the current Index is 0 (first row) or 
//       there has been no change in user or process comparing current/previous row
//   else return null
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(idx, "Custom", 
            each if [Index]=0 
            then 0
            else 
                if [Process] <> idx[Process]{[Index]-1} or [User] <> idx[User]{[Index]-1} then [Index] 
                else null),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),

//Fill down the custom column
//  now have same number for each interactive group
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Columns",{"Custom"}),

//Group by the "filled down" custom column with no aggregation
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {
        {"all", each _, type table [User=nullable text, Process=nullable text, Process2=nullable text, Custom=number]}
        }),

//add a one-based Index column to the grouped table
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Interaction ID", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Index",{"Custom"}),

//Re-expand the table
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "all", 
        {"User", "Process", "Process2"}, {"User", "Process", "Process2"})
in
    #"Expanded all"
```

**Source**
[image]

**Results**
[image]